# TSQL - Select rows with same column A but different column B

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm trying to find rows (Name) that does not have ID = 1. For example, if my table looked like this:

```
Name     ID        
--------------
A      1
A      0
B      1
B      0
C      0 
D      2
D      0
```

The answer to this query would be:

```
Name
-----
C
D
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM Table t0
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table t1
    WHERE t0.Name = t1.Name
    AND t1.Id = 1
)
```

Comment: gotqn's answer is much better though. There is no need to query the table multiple times here. When you only want a statement per name, then group by name.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Name
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Comment: HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 is equal to HAVING COUNT(ID) = 1  ?

Comment: @SQL_M: No. It's equal to `HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN ID = 1 THEN 'count this record' END) = 0`. We count the occurrences of ID = 1 per name here. `HAVING COUNT(ID) = 1` means `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`, so that's entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Distinct name 
From myTable
Where name not in (Select name From myTable Where id= 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(name)
FROM tbl t1 
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM tbl t2 WHERE ID=1 AND t1.name=t2.name)
```

Comment: That's the same as the accepted answer. Besides: remove the parentheses in `DISTINCT(name)`; they don't belong. `DISTINCT` is not a function. You wouldn't write `SELECT DISTINCT (firstname), (lastname)` instead of `SELECT DISTINCT firstname, lastname` either.